Sequelize: User is not associated to Commentaire
I am working with two Sequelize models: User and Comment. Each Comment belongs to a User, and a User can write multiple comments. My goal is to include all comments associated with each user in my JSON response.Here are the relevant models for User and Commentaire:
User Model:
`const { DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../config/db');

const Commentaire = sequelize.define('./Commentaire.js');

const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
    },
    nom: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    prenom: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    username: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
    },
    email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
    },
    phone: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    password: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    isActive: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    date_add: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW,
    },
    verification: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    tags: {
        type: DataTypes.JSON,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    type: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: true,
        defaultValue: null,
    },
}, {
    timestamps: true,
    modelName: 'User', 
});




 User.associate = (models) => {
    User.hasMany(Commentaire, {
        foreignKey: 'user',
        as: 'commentaires'
    });
}; 


User.sync()
    .then(() => console.log('Modèle User synchronisé avec la base de données'))
    .catch(err => console.error('Erreur de synchronisation du modèle User:', err));

module.exports = User;
`

Comment Model:
`const { DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../config/db');

const User = require('./User');

const Post = require('./Post');

const Commentaire = sequelize.define('Commentaire', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
    },
    commentaire: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    userId: { 
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
            model: User,  
            key: 'id', 
        }
    },
    postId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
            model: Post,  
            key: 'id', 
        }
    },
}, {
    timestamps: true, 
    modelName: 'Commentaire', 
});


Commentaire.associate = (models) => {
    Commentaire.belongsTo(User, {
        foreignKey: 'commentaires_ibfk_1', 
        as: 'id' 
    });
};
 


Commentaire.sync()
    .then(() => console.log('Modèle Commentaire synchronisé avec la base de données'))
    .catch(err => console.error('Erreur de synchronisation du modèle Commentaire:', err));

module.exports = Commentaire;
`

below is the index.js class :
`'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const process = require('process');
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.json')[env];
const db = {};

let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file => {
    return (
      file.indexOf('.') !== 0 &&
      file !== basename &&
      file.slice(-3) === '.js' &&
      file.indexOf('.test.js') === -1
    );
  })
  .forEach(file => {
    const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

db.User = require('./User')(sequelize);
db.Commentaire = require('./Commentaire')(sequelize);


module.exports = db;
`

this my function `
exports.getByPost = async(req, res) => {
    try {
        const postId = req.params.post; 

        const comments = await Commentaire.findAll({
            where: { user: postId },
            include: [{
                model: User
            }],

        });

        if (!comments.length) { 
            return res.json({ message: 'Aucun commentaire trouvé pour ce post' });
        }

        res.json({ message: 'Commentaires récupérés avec succès', comments });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        
        res.json({ message: 'Erreur lors de la récupération des commentaires', error });
    }
};

this is error
EagerLoadingError [SequelizeEagerLoadingError]: User is not associated to Commentaire!
    at Commentaire._getIncludedAssociation (C:\work-space\test-topmorer\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:565:13)
    at Commentaire._validateIncludedElement (C:\work-space\test-topmorer\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:502:53)
    at C:\work-space\test-topmorer\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:421:37
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Commentaire._validateIncludedElements (C:\work-space\test-topmorer\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:417:39)
    at Commentaire.findAll (C:\work-space\test-topmorer\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:1124:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)


Try to avoid importing models in each other modules. Use models.<ModelName> parameter in associate methods instead of indicating imported model

Thank you for your suggestion! I tried implementing it, but unfortunately, I didn't see any changes in the behavior of the code

I've had this issue before. Looking at your code, I think you can resolve it by changing commentaires_ibfk_1 to userId in the association between the User and Commentaire classes.
The foreignKey property in belongsTo should match the foreignKey property in hasMany.
Your association could look like this:
Commentaire.associate = (models) => {
  Commentaire.belongsTo(User, {
    foreignKey: 'userId', 
    as: 'id' 
  });
};


Even after trying your suggestion, I am still encountering the following error: EagerLoadingError [SequelizeEagerLoadingError]: Users is not associated to Posts!
